How does the `typecheck_fn` macro in the Linux kernel actually check the function type?
The file include/linux/typecheck.h of the Linux kernel contains this code:
/*
 * Check at compile time that 'function' is a certain type, or is a pointer
 * to that type (needs to use typedef for the function type.)
 */
#define typecheck_fn(type,function) \
({  typeof(type) __tmp = function; \
    (void)__tmp; \
})

I am familiar with GNU C's compound statement expression and typeof. From what I know, a pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer, so even if the types are different, the assignment should be okay.
But what is the last line doing? It appears to look like a NO-OP to me.
Would the above somehow fail to compile, or merely raise a diagnostic message unless -Werror was specified?

There are two other questions about typecheck.h, but they both ask about typecheck(), not typecheck_fn().

“… a pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again;… so even if the types are equal, the assignment should be okay” is not a valid inference. The fact a conversion is defined by the C standard means the behavior is defined when a program performs that conversion, as with a cast. It does not mean the types involved satisfy the constraints required of an assignment.

@EricPostpischil I see, I understood that to mean that the conversion will be implicit, or that a diagnostic would be required. Under GCC, a diagnostic message is emitted when I try assigning printf() to a function pointer declared as void (*f)(void). But it does not fail to compile. Is the purpose of this macro to just issue a warning?

The last line is probably to suppress the warning about a variable being defined but not used.

@user3840170 What I am really interested in is how this checks at compile-time whether the function is a certain type. To me, checking sounds like it should either fail to compile, or return some boolean value.

-Wincompatible-pointer-types takes care of it, it seems.

"To me, checking sounds like it should either fail to compile, or return some boolean value." - If a check fails to compile, then there is no reason for it to return a value. Most compile-time checks do nothing on success (that is, they do not affect on the generated object code). And typecheck_fn is one of such checks.

The type check macros in linux are there to make noise if they don't outright fail to compile with a wrong type. A warning about the wrong type being used is noticeable enough that you won't get code merged into linux with that error. No need to return a bool. IF they would return a bool then the only use case for that would be to assert it and then the macro should do that internally in the first place.
